# play from iPhone main speaker and earpiece speaker simultaneously using AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute

Tags: iphone, ios6, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

Does anyone know if an iPhone can play a sound from the main speaker (bottom of phone next to 30-pin dock connector) and the receiver (earpiece speaker above screen) simultaneously using `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute` (or any other methods)?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it cannot. Unfortunately, when a 30 pin dock connector is plugged in and an audio pair is made all audio is routed to the 30 pin connector. This can sometimes even happen by something as simple as crap getting jammed in the 30 pin - as far as piggybacking over the hardware, it's a definite no unfortunately - check out the http://theamazingaudioengine.com/ to see probably the coolest stuff you can do with audio at the moment, but in answer to your question, no it can't be done sorry.